# Как сравнить два списка и сделать общий список по условию

Tags: python, список

```
a = [['лестница', '2', 'False'], ['кирпич', '3', 'False'], ['обои', '4', 'False']]
b = [['лестница', '2', 'True'], ['кирпич', '3', 'True']]
# результат должен быть следующим
res = [['лестница', '2', 'True'], ['кирпич', '3', 'True'], ['обои', '4', 'False']]
```

В общем приходит список `b`. Надо сравнить его со списком `a` и, если список `b` не соответствует `a` полностью, как в данном примере, добавить недостающий элемент в `b`, в данном случае `['обои', '4', 'False']`.
Как это сделать? Сравнить нормально через циклы не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [['лестница', '2', 'False'], ['кирпич', '3', 'False'], ['обои', '4', 'False']]
b = [['лестница', '2', 'True'], ['кирпич', '3', 'True']]

b.extend(x for x in a if x[0] not in [y[0] for y in b])
```

b:

```
[['лестница', '2', 'True'], ['кирпич', '3', 'True'], ['обои', '4', 'False']]
```

Comment: Одни внешние квадратные скобки можно убрать внутри `extend` )

Comment: @CrazyElf убрал, хотя эксплицитный список выглядит каноничнее ;)

Comment: Я чета такое и делал, как у вас это дело в столбце выглядит можете показать?

Comment: @Freerade не понял вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [['лестница', '2', 'False'], ['кирпич', '3', 'False'], ['обои', '4', 'False']]
b = [['лестница', '2', 'True'], ['кирпич', '3', 'True']]
for i in a: # пробегаемся по списку a
    if i[0] in [j[0] for j in b]: # проверяем соответствие списка b к списку a
        continue # список соответствует - продолжаем проходить по циклу
    else:
        b += [i] # список не соответствует - добавляем недостающий элемент в список b
print(b) # выводим получившийся список
```

вывод:

```
 [['лестница', '2', 'True'], ['кирпич', '3', 'True'], ['обои', '4', 'False']]
```

Comment: а почему вы решили, что порядок элементов в списках одинаков? замените ваш a на `[['лестница', '2', 'False'], ['обои', '4', 'False'], ['кирпич', '3', 'False']]` и проверьте результат.

Comment: Так в том то и прикол, надо чтоб во всех случаях работало.

Comment: Сейчас попробую подправить.